# RuntimeException when camera is tilted from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, file-io, hardware

I have a Fragment which uses a `CameraPreview` like so:

```
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

This works fine - opens up a camera view as intended. However, when I tilt the camera from portrait to landscape I get a `RuntimeException`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:413)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
        at com.example.sv_laptop03.myApp.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:36)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:610)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:93)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:182)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:864)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and it specifically complains about the first line in the `else` block of this method:

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); // WITHOUT THIS MY CAMERA AXIS' ARE FLIPPED
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open(); // RUNTIME EXCEPTION HERE
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I included permissions in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Does anybody know what could be causing the crash? It seems to work fine on a Galaxy S6 but crashes on my S3. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit:

I added this in my Activity, now the app crashes before the camera loads.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.release();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera.open();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to call release() when you are being destroyed?

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).